# how to ignore xml namespaces?

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-namespaces

I've got test xml file that looks like this:

```
<Person>
  <ContactInfo>
   ...
  <ContactInfo>
</Person>
```

When I'm trying to deserialize, everything works fine. 
But the problem is that sometimes the structure of this xml file is different - xml namespaces are added sometimes.

```
<Person xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <ContactInfo>
   ...
  <ContactInfo>
</Person>
```

And now when I'm serializing, I get IOnvalidOperationException: "There is an error in XML document (1, 2)". The inner exception message says `<Person  xmlns='http://tempuri.org/PaymentInformationXml.xsd'>` was not expected.

So could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What are you using to deserialize?

Comment: Your example XML and the error message are not consistent; the xsi/xsd are just namespace aliases - they don't change anything. You can pretty-much ignore those two. However, `xmlns='...blah...'` is **very** important. Please clarify: is this in your XML or not? If it is, you must tell XmlSerializer in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A namespace is fundamental in XML (unlike namespaces which are interchangeable). If Person is in that namespace, you must tell it:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/PaymentInformationXml.xsd")]
public class Person {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [XmlSerializerNamespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces.aspx).

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Controlling the **default namespace** can be done directly on the XmlSerializer:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person), "http://tempuri.org/PaymentInformationXml.xsd");
```

... but your question is a little unclear about where the problem comes from.

Check your `Person` classes `[XmlType]` attribute:

```
[XmlType(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/PaymentInformationXml.xsd")]
public class Person
{
    //...
}
```

The namespace for your `Person` type needs to be consistent with the one you use when serializing.

Comment: The issue is not the xsi/xsd, but rather xmlns= which means XmlSerializerNamespaces doesn't do anything here,

Answer (score 1):

there's an article about xml [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/05/05/tr.html)

And i also stumbled accros this piece of code: (very helpfull)

```
XmlDocument stripDocumentNamespace(XmlDocument oldDom)
{
// Remove all xmlns:* instances from the passed XmlDocument
// to simplify our xpath expressions.
XmlDocument newDom = new XmlDocument();
newDom.LoadXml(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
oldDom.OuterXml, @"(xmlns:?[^=]*=[""][^""]*[""])", "",
System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline)
);
return newDom;
}
```

hope this could help

Comment: You forgot the prefixes.