# When do you have to specify the root node to deserialize xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to deserialize xml coming from a web API service. It works only if I instantiate the XmlSerializer object with the root node- XmlRootAttribute type- that specifies the name of the root node and the namespace. If it is proper xml with only one root node, why do I need to tell it the name of the root? I see examples where people aren't doing that. I'd like to keep this as generic as possible.

[image: XML]

This is the code to deserialize. I'd like the commented out line to work where I don't specify the root node, but it gives the error at the bottom.

```
public static T xmlToObject<T>(string strXML)
        {
            XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
            xRoot.ElementName = "QIMonthReturn";
            xRoot.Namespace = "QI.Measures.API";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), xRoot);
            //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); 

            StringReader rdr = new StringReader(strXML);

            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
        }
```

Error (I took out angle brackets):

```
{"There is an error in XML document (2, 2)."}
{"QIMonthReturn xmlns='QI.Measures.API' was not expected."}
```

Classes:

```
public class QIMonth
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Date", DataType = "dateTime")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Numerator", DataType = "boolean")]
    public bool Numerator { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Denominator", DataType = "boolean")]
    public bool Denominator { get; set; }
}   

[XmlRoot("QIMonthReturn")]
public class QIMonthReturn
{
    public QIMonthReturn()
    {         
        Months = new List<QIMonth>();
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PatientKey")]
    public string PatientKey { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Months"), XmlArrayItem("QIMonth")]  
    public List<QIMonth> Months { get; set; }
}
```

I did have XmlRoot attribute above QIMonth but took it out, don't know if that was needed.

Where I'm adding the namespace:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {           
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new CustomNamespaceXmlFormatter("QI.Measures.API") { UseXmlSerializer = true });
    }
```

Comment: Show us your C# class model definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the namespace to your model class, your code will work. In your question, you had the namespace redacted, so I made one up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QIMonthReturn xmlns="SomeNamespaceHere">
    <PatientKey>25</PatientKey>
    <Months>
        <QIMonth>
            <Date>2018-05-03T11:13:02.1312881-04:00</Date>
            <Numerator>false</Numerator>
            <Denominator>true</Denominator>
        </QIMonth>
    </Months>
</QIMonthReturn>


[XmlRoot("QIMonthReturn", Namespace="SomeNamespaceHere")]
public class QIMonthReturn
{
    public QIMonthReturn()
    {
        Months = new List<QIMonth>();
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PatientKey")]
    public string PatientKey { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Months"), XmlArrayItem("QIMonth")]
    public List<QIMonth> Months { get; set; }
}

public static T xmlToObject<T>(string strXML)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    StringReader rdr = new StringReader(strXML);

    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
}
```

Referencing Marc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730989/7495)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am adding the namespace in another place in the WebApiConfig class since I add a custom class to do XML formatting so it won't add the two namespaces Web API automatically adds.  I will add that as well (I fear my question is getting very bloated)

Comment: I didn't see how you added the namespace to the XmlRoot attribute- now that I did that, I am able to run it without specifying the namespace when deserializing (and I still have just one namespace!). Sweet